# Unable to populate a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn created at design time

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

I have a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn being craeted at design time.But I want to polulate it at runtime. But it is not happening.

Here is the entire code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<FileInformation> FileInformationList;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PrepareGrid();
            DisplayResult();
        }

        private void PrepareGrid()
        {

            var fileNameColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            {
                Name = @"FileName",
                HeaderText = "File Name",
                DataPropertyName = @"FileName",
                AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill,
                ReadOnly = false,
                Frozen = false
            };
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(fileNameColumn);

            var downloadColumn = new DataGridViewLinkColumn

            {
                Name = @"Download",
                HeaderText = @"Download",
                DataPropertyName = @"Download",
                AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill,
                ReadOnly = true
            };
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(downloadColumn);

            var dropdownColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

            {
                Name = @"Test",
                HeaderText = @"Country",                
                AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill,
                ReadOnly = true
            };
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dropdownColumn);
        }

        private void DisplayResult()
        {
            FileInformationList = LoadItems();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = FileInformationList;

            ((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns["Test"]).DataSource = GetCountryList();
            ((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns["Test"]).ValueMember = "id";
            ((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns["Test"]).DisplayMember = "Name";

        }

        private List<FileInformation> LoadItems()
        {
            var lstScriptInfo = new List<FileInformation>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                lstScriptInfo.Add(new FileInformation { FileName = "File" + i.ToString() + ".txt" });
            }
            return lstScriptInfo;
        }

        private DataTable GetCountryList()
        {
            DataTable CountryDt = new DataTable();
            CountryDt.Columns.Add("id");
            CountryDt.Columns.Add("Name");
            CountryDt.Rows.Add("1", "Canada");
            CountryDt.Rows.Add("2", "USA");
            return CountryDt;
        }

    }

    public class FileInformation
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string Download { get { return "Download File"; } }
    }
}
```

The output is

[image]

Please help me to identity what has went wrong?

Comment: Is combobox empty or not showing value initially?

Comment: not showing initial value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to achieve that:

1. Setting defualt null value for column (skipped null checks):

   ```
   var cbColumn = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns["Test"];
   var ds = GetCountryList();

   cbColumn.DataSource = ds;
   cbColumn.ValueMember = "id";
   cbColumn.DisplayMember = "Name";

   cbColumn.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = ds.Rows[0][0];
   cbColumn.DefaultCellStyle.DataSourceNullValue  = ds.Rows[0][1];
   ```
2. Second is to iterate after `DataBinding` and set it manually:

   ```
   private void DataGridDataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
   {
       foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
       {
           var hasValue = row.Cells["Test"].Value != null;

           if (!hasValue)
           {
                row.Cells["Test"].Value = 1;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

also I'd change binding order:

```
private void DisplayResult()
{
    var cbColumn = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns["Test"];
    var ds = GetCountryList();

    cbColumn.DataSource = ds;
    cbColumn.ValueMember = "id";
    cbColumn.DisplayMember = "Name";

    cbColumn.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = ds.Rows[0][0];
    cbColumn.DefaultCellStyle.DataSourceNullValue  = ds.Rows[0][1];

    FileInformationList = LoadItems();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = FileInformationList;
}
```

Comment: Getting error at ds[0].Name: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataTable'

Comment: Ahh sorry, forgotten that you are using `DataTable` as data source, fixed and try again :)