# is there any way to simplify this code? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, simplify

here is the code, is there any way to simplify this code so i dont have to write all combobox"x" down, i wonder what happen if there are 1000 comboboxes.

```
For a = 1 To 8
        qty = qty + 1
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(qty)
        ComboBox2.Items.Add(qty)
        ComboBox3.Items.Add(qty)
        ComboBox4.Items.Add(qty)
        ComboBox5.Items.Add(qty)
        ComboBox6.Items.Add(qty)
        ComboBox7.Items.Add(qty)
        ComboBox8.Items.Add(qty)
        ComboBox9.Items.Add(qty)
        ComboBox10.Items.Add(qty)
        ComboBox11.Items.Add(qty)
        ComboBox12.Items.Add(qty)
        ComboBox13.Items.Add(qty)
        ComboBox14.Items.Add(qty)
        ComboBox15.Items.Add(qty)
        ComboBox16.Items.Add(qty)
        ComboBox17.Items.Add(qty)
        ComboBox18.Items.Add(qty)
        ComboBox19.Items.Add(qty)
        ComboBox20.Items.Add(qty)
    Next
```

Edit :
i mean, can i add the "qty" value to all my combobox without calling all my combobox 1 by 1 in the code, im very new to coding

Comment: Maybe use numericupdown control with min set to 1 and max set to 8?

Comment: could you explain please? im pretty new to coding @peterG

Comment: Your code fragment seems to be loading 20 comboboxes with the numbers 1 to 8. You could replace the comboboxes with numericupdown controls to achieve a similar UX, without any code. To answer your other question - 1000 comboboxes is unlikely to be a good design, but if you insisted on doing that you can use a for-next loop and add a control to the form eachiteration, incrementing the  position as you go.

Comment: Since everything is hardcoded, just enter 1-8 in the designer.  Read [ask] and taker the [tour]

Comment: another alternative could be `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` as it can reuse the same ComboBox for all cells https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230071/unable-to-populate-a-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-created-at-design-time

Comment: You might want to add what you're doing with all of these comboboxes along with the fact as to why you don't know how many there Might be. Since this is the code and not something the user has control over, I would think the programmer would have this information, otherwise, it sounds more like you should be asking the best way to do what you're wanting to do.